# Autocomplete in golang in emacs

Tags: go, emacs, autocomplete

I'm aware a lot is involved in getting autocomplete to work in emacs, including:

- auto-complete
- company
- flymake

I am not sure which components are responsible for which aspects.  What is the package that when I start typing...

```
fmt.P
```

Would finish with

```
fmt.Println
```

?

I believe I have company as my auto-complete, and at present, if I start:

```
fm
```

It finishes fmt, but

```
fmt.
```

Produces nothing, and

```
fmt.P
```

Produces

```
fmt.package
```

Which is entirely wrong.  What package should I investigate to understand what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autocomplete, company-mode, flymake, oh my.  I recommend you uninstall all of the above and use Emacs' native completion instead:

1. install [gocode](https://github.com/nsf/gocode) and make sure the binary is in Emacs' `PATH`;
2. install the [go-complete](https://github.com/vibhavp/go-complete) package in Emacs (I got it from `melpa`, but you may prefer to install it manually);
3. add the following to your `.emacs`:

   ```
   (add-hook 'completion-at-point-functions 'go-complete-at-point)
   ```
4. press `M-TAB` in a `go-mode` buffer.

Comment: Thanks, @jch.  Most works, but what is the component of autocomplete that should correct my fmt.PrintLn and replace with fmt.Println with a lowercase L?

Comment: That's strange.  Probably a weird configuration on your side, please check your completion-at-point-functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since the original answer was written, the original gocode has ceased being maintained.  While there exist forks of gocode that work well with recent versions of Go, the recommended replacement is [golsp](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/tools/cmd/golsp)

1. Install the `eglot` pakage from ELPA (not necessary if you are running Emacs 29 or later, which includes `eglot` out of the box).
2. Install `golsp` and make sure it is in your path.
3. Add the following to your `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook #'eglot-ensure)
```

4. Press `M-TAB` in a `go-mode` buffer.